# How to make all the windows to have the same size of icons?

Tags: windows-8

I'm sick and tired of constantly having to scroll the mouse wheel (with control key) to change the size of the icons in **every** new window. Is there a way to customize a window (show/hide panes, set the size of the icons etc. and then tell the computer to use **just that** appearance?

I recall, looong time ago, in a windows version far, far away, it was possible to click "use in all windows". However, that doesn't seem to be available in the version I'm on now (Win 8). Is there a trick to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are *a number of different folder types or **templates***, and that setting the icon size in one folder type might not set it for another. For example, you might want to set large icons for the Pictures Template and small for the Document Templates. See [Folder Template - Set Default for All Folders in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9288-folder-template-set-default-all-folders-windows-8-a.html) and [Change folder views and behavior](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-folder-views-and-behavior).

Select a folder, or even a whole drive, right-click and select *Properties*, and *Optimize* it for a specific file type (template).

My own experience has been that, once you've got these set, don't make subsequent changes, as changing one can influence the other settings.

Answer (score 2):

Close all windows, open a one, adjust your view preferences, then (as in the picture) go to Folder options, View tab, click on Apply to Folders button, answer Yes.

[image]

Comment: Basically the same place it's been since XP (or before). ;)